# Is there any size limit of SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Actually I did some research and found one implementation document, http://sqlite.org/limits.html but could not find the exact answer to this. i.e. what is the exact data limit of a whole sqlite database?

Comment: Share your research, otherwise it's just a lie.

Comment: check the post once again. I think its more specific with what you needed to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximum database size is approximately **1.4e+14 bytes**

> Every database consists of one or more "pages". Within a single
>   database, every page is the same size, but different database can have
>   page sizes that are powers of two between 512 and 65536, inclusive.
>   **The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages**. At the maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum
>   database size of approximately **1.4e+14 bytes** (140 terabytes, or 128
>   tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).
>
> This particular upper bound is untested since the developers do not
>   have access to hardware capable of reaching this limit. However, tests
>   do verify that SQLite behaves correctly and sanely when a database
>   reaches the maximum file size of the underlying filesystem (which is
>   usually much less than the maximum theoretical database size) and when
>   a database is unable to grow due to disk space exhaustion.

For more info see [Maximum Database Size](http://sqlite.org/limits.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is not important how much data a database can store. The question is at what level the orations in database are not efficient any more! Or in other word, at what level there are better options. One alternative option can be another DBMS which handles large amount of data better. Or another could be NoSql databases. 

The thing is definition of efficiency differs in each application. For one application waiting 1 second for retrieving data may be Ok while in another even 200 ms is a killer.

Also the type of query you're running on a database has a huge impact on performance so its not just the data. queries also matter! 

Normally you don't have to think about this stuff! You should be able to store tens of thousand of rows in each table without any problem! But if you want, you can always make your own tests to see the current situation of your application satisfies you or not!! Writing tests is quiet easy, for example if you have a select query first make sure you put enough test data in the database (always think about worth case scenario) Then execute the query for 10,000 times using a loop.By measuring the time and dividing it by 10,000. you get time required for a single operation. don't forget to do this on different devices to get more precise result. The result you get from this kind of tests is worth more than any statistics because

- It's about your app and its database!
- It's about the amount of performance and efficiency you care about.
- It's about the types of queries you are runing on you'r database.

Another think worth paying attention is running queries on sqlite doesn't return the actual data! It gives you a cursor and using the cursor you can retrieve the data. executing a query usually takes few millisecond while using a loop to retrieve the data takes few hundreds of milliseconds. Understanding this time difference is very important if you care about performance. The key thing is you don't have to get whole data as once! Get the data at a time you need it. So it doesn't matter if your query returns 1 million rows as long as you handle them one bye one! 
So if you not satisfied with tests i mentioned before first think you need to think about is how are you handling cursor object?!

let us know if you have any issue in particular.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://sqlite.org/faq.html

> 1.0 The Database File
>
> The complete state of an SQLite database is usually contained a single
>   file on disk called the "main database file".
>
> During a transaction, SQLite stores additional information in a second
>   file called the "rollback journal", or if SQLite is in WAL mode, a
>   write-ahead log file. If the application or host computer crashes
>   before the transaction completes, then the rollback journal or
>   write-ahead log contains critical state information needed to restore
>   the main database file to a consistent state. When a rollback journal
>   or write-ahead log contains information necessary for recovering the
>   state of the database, they are called a "hot journal" or "hot WAL
>   file". Hot journals and WAL files are only a factor during error
>   recovery scenarios and so are uncommon, but they are part of the state
>   of an SQLite database and so cannot be ignored. This document defines
>   the format of a rollback journal and the write-ahead log file, but the
>   focus is on the main database file.
>
> 1.1 Pages
>
> The main database file consists of one or more pages. The size of a
>   page is a power of two between 512 and 65536 inclusive. All pages
>   within the same database are the same size. The page size for a
>   database file is determined by the 2-byte integer located at an offset
>   of 16 bytes from the beginning of the database file.
>
> Pages are numbered beginning with 1. The maximum page number is
>   2147483646 (231 - 2). The minimum size SQLite database is a single
>   512-byte page. The maximum size database would be 2147483646 pages at
>   65536 bytes per page or 140,737,488,224,256 bytes (about 140
>   terabytes). Usually SQLite will hit the maximum file size limit of the
>   underlying filesystem or disk hardware size limit long before it hits
>   its own internal size limit.
>
> In common use, SQLite databases tend to range in size from a few
>   kilobytes to a few gigabytes.
>
> At any point in time, every page in the main database has a single use
>   which is one of the following:
>
> The lock-byte page A freelist page A freelist trunk page A freelist
>   leaf page A b-tree page A table b-tree interior page A table b-tree
>   leaf page An index b-tree interior page An index b-tree leaf page A
>   payload overflow page A pointer map page